# I have an error in MySQL connection using node js

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect google cloud MySQL using node js but i get this error

[image: this is error image]

How to solve this error.

Comment: This is a connection timed out error. This means your code cannot connect to Cloud SQL. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you so much. I got it

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still need to add further information for your question to become solvable.

Answer (score 1):

It's connection time out error so I can see two possibilities:

**1) You are trying to connect to a wrong IP address**

Make sure the IP address is correct, check the correct IP address by visiting Cloud SQL -> YOUR INSTANCE -> Overview Page -> Connect to this instance:
[image]

**2) You have not configured external access to your Cloud SQL instance**

By default Cloud SQL won't allow connections outside Google Cloud network. To give access to your client:

- Learn your IP address (https://www.whatismyip.com/)
- In the Instances page in the Google Cloud Platform Console, click the instance to open its Overview page.
- Select the Connections tab.
- Under Authorized networks, click Add network and enter the IP address of the client machine where your client is installed.
- Click Done, then click Save at the bottom of your page to save your changes:

[image]